# How implement a proper layout using reactjs and react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, react-router, url-routing

How can I implement a proper layout using `reactjs` and `react-router`.
Basically what I want to implement is something line the image below:

[image]

Note: I don't want implement the `header & footer` in the `index.html`.

So far what I have done and working is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'


class App extends React.Component {
    render(){
    return <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/blog">Blog</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/portfolio">Portfolio</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/social">Social</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/about">about</Link></li>
        </ul>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
  }
}

class Home extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <p>home</p>
  }
}

class Blog extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <p>blog</p>
  }
}

class Portfolio extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <p>portfolio</p>
  }
}

class Social extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <p>social</p>
  }
}

class About extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <p>about</p>
  }
}

let routes = <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="home" component={Home} />
        <Route path="blog" component={Blog} />
        <Route path="portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
        <Route path="social" component={Social} />
        <Route path="about" component={About} />
      </Route>
    </Router>

React.render(routes, document.body);
```

The above code it's working properly, but What I need is separate the the App in 3 components - > `<Header />`, `content` and `<Footer />`

something like:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <Header />
           {this.props.children}
           <Footer />
  }
}

class Footer extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div>Footer</div>
  }
}


class Header extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return <div>
        <h1>App</h1>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="/home">Home</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/blog">Blog</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/portfolio">Portfolio</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/social">Social</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="/about">about</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  }
}
```

but when I implement it the routing doesn't work and I don't get any error, I think is something related with the `{this.props.children}`, so.. any idea how can I get it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your render function transpiles to:

```
function render() {
  return React.createElement(Header, null);
  {
    this.props.children;
  }
  React.createElement(Footer, null);
}
```

You're not seeing any errors because this is valid, but has unreachable code. It just returns a `Header` element.

You need to wrap its contents in another element, e.g.:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      <Header/>
      {this.props.children}
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  }
}
```

---

Edit: Imagine you wrote this code outside the context of React - what would you expect it to return?

```
function render() {
  return 'Header';
         'Content';
         'Footer';
}
```

These are 3 separate statements, and since the first statement is a `return`, the last 2 are irrelevant, as they'll never be reached.

In order to return multiple objects from a function, you need to put them in a container of some sort, e.g. an Array:

```
function render() {
  return [
    'Header',
    'Content',
    'Footer'
  ]
}
```

However, you can't do this in a React component's `render()` method, as [they must return either a React component, `null`, or `false`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#render), hence you need to wrap contents with another element if you want to return multiple items.

Comment: Thanks! it's working, but I don't understand why we should wrap them in another element. @jonny-buchanan

Comment: Added an extra section to attempt to explain this - any better?